# locating an address in android phone

Tags: android, api, google-maps, location, street-address

in my android application i have address, when i click a button i have to call google map api and show the exact location of that address.how to use that google map api in android , and also how to send the addess to the particular api to locate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the location of an address you need to use the geocoding service from google maps, http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding. After you get the coordinates from the server (latitude and longitude) you have to show them on your map.

To show a map in an android application, you would have to use this api: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Comment: hey the link were really informative. in the first link how can i get my lati and langitude values? i couldn't find any variable retrieving it. how to form a geocode request object from android and how to reuse it?

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests here's how to form a geocode request and receive the result!